# Anime about high school student that protect their school from monster or maybe ghost

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember watching this anime when I was a kid around 2008. Here's the details that I remember about this anime:

- There are two main characters, male and female
- They wear some kind of Japanese traditional outfit, and they fight always at night
- Their power was that they were able to make some kind of block that is transparent to capture the monster or ghost like creature.
- They were defending the school, because the monster was attracted to the spiritual power from the school
- Also if I'm not wrong, they are always accompanied by a spirit dog
- I watched it on TV. I'm from Indonesia and I remember the channel name was Antv

Comment: This is a nice start, can you remember roughly when you watched this as we don't know when you were a kid? If English sin't your first language did you watch it in another language? Can you remember where you saw it? If on TV, what channel? Can you remember why the monsters were attacking them or them the monsters? Why are they capturing them not killing them? Where did it take place? A school, temple, middle of nowhere, inside, outside, etc.? If you remember anything else about this please [edit] your question to add that detail in.

Comment: i added more detail, that i can remember. and sorry if there so much bad grammar

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Kekkaishi*** by Yellow Watanabe.

[image: promotion image]

Synopsis by [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/1606/Kekkaishi_TV):

> **Yoshimura Sumimura** comes from a long line of "Kekkaishi," individuals who have supernatural abilities and are able to destroy evil creatures called Ayakashi that venture into the human realm from time to time. **The Ayakashi are demons that look to feast on the power emanating from the land of Karasumori, which also happens to be where Yoshimura's high school is located.** Now, Yoshimura must fight to protect his beloved school and hometown. Although, if it were up to him, he would rather be baking cakes than **fighting off the ugly characters that show up at night.**
>
> Thankfully, Yoshimura isn't the only one helping to keep the baddies at bay. **His childhood friend and neighbor, Tokine Yukimura,** joins him in this righteous battle. Despite the fact that they are from rival clans, these two make a fantastic team. And teamwork is something vital to fighting the evil that is closing in, as the Ayakashi attack in waves, looking to claim the land as their own, and a shadowy organization looks on, ready to pounce when the time is right...
>
> <sup>(Emphasis added to match the description on the question)</sup>

The promotional image shows the characters in Japanese traditional outfit with a spirit dog behind them. The original running time in Japan is 2006-2008.

---

Found by searching `anime antv` which returned [a list of old anime on Indonesian TV channels](https://www.wattpad.com/535909383-obrolan-seputar-anime-%E3%80%8Banime-jadul-yang-pernah) and comparing them with the most likely candidate title.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't think that searching anime antv would be helping at all.
Thanks a lot, definitely gonna re watch it again in this quarantine day.